# Convert characters to upper without changing original array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code which changes lowercase letters to uppercase letters of the private instance array letters and returns a string.

```
public String toUpperCase()
{
    char[] duplicate = new char [letters.length];
    duplicate = letters;
    String upperCase = "";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < duplicate.length; i++)
    {
        a = duplicate[i];
        if (a >= 97 && a <= 122)
            {
                b = a - 32;
                duplicate[i] = (char) b;
            }
        upperCase = upperCase + duplicate[i];
    }
    return upperCase;
}
```

the problem is the original contents of the array letters have been changed to uppercase after this method is called. I created a new array, duplicate, and set it equal to letters in hopes I can change the lowercase letters in the array letters to uppercase without changing the original array. However, this didn't work. How can I change the lowercase letters of the array letters to uppercase without changing the original array?

Comment: You're passing nothing as argument to this fucntion?

Comment: `duplicate = letters;` ... you are assigning the original value to the duplicates, these two arrays now point to the same location

Comment: I have the instance array in my code I just didn't include it

Comment: Unrelated, but for better readability, write character constants as such e.g. in the check "if (a >= 97 && a <= 122)" it would be much clearer if you write "if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`duplicate = letters;` ... you are assigning the original value to the duplicates, these two arrays now point to the same location.  So any modifications to `duplicate` will be mirrored by `letters` automatically (they both point to the same location in memory).

Instead, you need to use `letters` to obtain the original values and store the modifications within `duplicate`

```
public String toUpperCase() {
    char[] duplicate = new char[letters.length];
    String upperCase = "";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        a = letters[i];
        if (a >= 97 && a <= 122) {
            b = a - 32;
            duplicate[i] = (char) b;
        }
        upperCase = upperCase + duplicate[i];
    }
    return upperCase;
}
```

Unless you have some reason not to, you can also make use of the `Character` class to help you detect lower case characters and convert them to upper case, for example...

```
if (Character.isLowerCase(a)) {
    letters[i] = Character.toUpperCase(a);
}
```

or you could just use `letters[i] = Character.toUpperCase(a);` as it won't double convert upper case characters

This all leads me to wonder why you need the `duplicate` array to begin with, in the end, you could just get away with something like...

```
public String toUpperCase() {
    StringBuilder upperCase = new StringBuilder(letters.length);
    for (char c : letters) {
        upperCase.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }
    return upperCase.toString();
}
```

or just

```
public String toUpperCase() {
    return new String(letters).toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: I see, so I was able to change lowercase to uppercase not because I created a duplicate, but because I was referring the original array the whole time.

Comment: Well, that's what was changing your `letters` array, but, I'm not sure you actually need the `duplicate` array at all

Comment: The reason for this program is to get an idea of how toUpperCase() may work. Even if my code isn't exactly how it's programmed. Using the same array of characters I have created a substring method that prints a substring depending on the int arguments passed to substring. So i'm just programming methods like toUpperCase, toLowerCase, substring, charAt and indexOf to get an idea of how these may work.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
char[] duplicate = letters.clone();
```

that way the original array does not change

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change the lowercase letters of the array letters to uppercase without changing the original array?

Don't assign the `letter` array instance to the variable `duplicate`. Instead use `System.arraycopy(letters, 0, duplicate, 0, letters.length)` which copies the contents of `letters` to `duplicate`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
char[] duplicate = new char [letters.length];
duplicate = letters;
```

The first line allocates a new array. The second line does *not* fill the new array. Far from it. The second line points `duplicate` to `letters`. That is, duplicate and letters both point to the same data. Manipulating duplicate manipulates letters too.

To make duplicate a real duplicate, you need to copy the content. An easy way to do just that:

```
char[] duplicate = letters.clone();
```

Another way to copy the content:

```
char[] duplicate = new char [letters.length];
System.arraycopy(letters, 0, duplicate, 0, letters.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

While other answers work too, you don't actually have to copy the array...

Just do,

```
    if (a >= 97 && a <= 122)
        {
            b = a - 32;
            upperCase = upperCase + (char) b;
        }
    else
        upperCase = upperCase + duplicate[i];
```